# count the occurrences of each word in that phrase using C language

Tags: c

I am not understanding why, when I am doing `sub=strtok(NULL,delim);`, instead of going to the next word, it is making it null. Please try this code and help me resolve the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100],str1[100],*sub,*sub1;
    int c1;
    printf("\nEnter the string or sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);
    strcpy(str1,str);
    char delim[]=" ";
    sub=strtok(str,delim);
    while(sub !=NULL)
    {
        c1=0;
        sub1=strtok(str1,delim);
        while(sub1 !=NULL)
        {
          if(!strcmp(sub,sub1))
          {
             c1++;
          }
          sub1=strtok(NULL,delim);
        }
        printf("\n%s : %d",sub,c1);
        sub=strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it that you think this call to `strtok` should do, and why do you think that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse multiple string buffers concurrently with `strtok()`, like you are trying to do. Internally, `strtok()` maintains a static reference to the input string, that is how it knows which string to advance through when subsequent calls specify a `NULL` string pointer.

Before entering your outer loop, you call `strtok(str)` to set the internal reference to `str`.  Then, inside the loop, you call `strtok(str1)` to reset that reference to `str1`.  So, on the 1st iteration of your outer loop, before entering the inner loop, `strtok()` has already lost its reference to your `str` buffer since you replace it with the `str1` buffer.  Then, after the inner loop has finished scanning `str1`, your outer loop breaks when calling `sub=strtok(NULL,delim);` because there are no more tokens to read from `str1`.

For what you are attempting, use [`strtok_r()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) instead:

> The `strtok_r()` function is a reentrant version `strtok()`. The `saveptr` argument is a pointer to a `char *` variable that is used internally by `strtok_r()` in order to maintain context between successive calls that parse the same string.
>
> ...
>
> **Different strings may be parsed concurrently using sequences of calls to `strtok_r()` that specify different `saveptr` arguments.**

Also, because `strtok(_r)()` is destructive to the input string, inserting `'\0'` after each token found, you need to reset the contents of your 2nd string buffer back to the original string before entering the inner loop.  Otherwise, the inner loop will stop scanning after is reads the 1st word in your 2nd string buffer.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char orig[100], str1[100], str2[100], *sub1, *sub2, *save1, *save2;
    char delim[] = " ";
    int c1;

    printf("\nEnter the string or sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", orig);

    strcpy(str1, orig);
    sub1 = strtok_r(str1, delim, &save1);
    while (sub1 != NULL)
    {
        c1 = 0;

        strcpy(str2, orig);
        sub2 = strtok_r(str2, delim, &save2);
        while (sub2 != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(sub1, sub2) == 0)
            {
                ++c1;
            }
            sub2 = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save2);
        }

        printf("\n%s : %d", sub1, c1);

        sub1 = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a single loop through a single string buffer, storing the word counts in a separate array, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _wordInfo
{
    char* str;
    int count;
} wordInfo;

int main()
{
    char str[100], *sub;
    char delim[] = " ";
    wordInfo words[100], *word;
    int numWords = 0;

    printf("\nEnter the string or sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);

    sub = strtok(str, delim);
    while (sub != NULL)
    {
        word = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i)
        {
            if (strcmp(sub, words[i].str) == 0)
            {
                word = &words[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!word)
        {
            if (numWords == 100) break;
            word = &words[numWords++];
            word->str = sub;
            word->count = 1;
        }
        else {
            word->count++;
        }

        sub = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i)
    {
        word = &words[i];
        printf("\n%s : %d", word->str, word->count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```